# Angular ui-slider - dynamic min/max values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

I'm using the angular ui-slider, and I need to load the slider's min- and max values from an external source so that I can set them like this:

```
$scope.minMaxValues = {
      slider1: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200
      },
      slider2: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200
      },
      slider3: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200
      },
      slider4: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200
      },
      slider5: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200
      }
    };
```

My HTML-looks like this:

```
<div class = "ui-slider-range ui-slider-handle" ui-slider="{range: true}" min="minMaxValues.slider1.min" max="minMaxValues.slider1.max" step="0.01" use-decimals ng-model="sliderValues[0]"></div>
```

Any suggestions on how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since ui-slider uses attributes on that directive, you need pass actual values:

`<div class = "ui-slider-range ui-slider-handle" ui-slider="{range: true}" min="{{minMaxValues.slider1.min}}" max="{{minMaxValues.slider1.max}}" step="0.01" use-decimals ng-model="sliderValues[0]"></div>`